# Conda can't install scikit-learn: post-link failed (699)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, conda, miniconda

Whenever I try to install scikit-learn with conda, I get this "post-link failed" error.

Here are the commands I used to install scikit-learn:

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

or I try to install in while creating the env:

```
conda create --prefix ./env pandas numpy matplotlib scikit-learn
```

Conda installs all of the packages except scikit-learn. Here's the error:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::scikit-learn-0.24.2-py39hf11a4ad_1'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::scikit-learn-0.24.2-py39hf11a4ad_1
location of failed script: C:\Users\Uzivatel\Desktop\programování\python\MLztm\sample\env\Scripts\.scikit-learn-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout: subdir: win-64

stderr: Access denied.

return code: 1
```

How can I solve this "post-link failed" issue?

Comment: It looks like you may have some files from a previous install of scikit-learn. Can you try to uninstall all versions (and possibly manually remove directories) of scikit-learn and then try again?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a strange bug with `%PREFIX%` variable assignment in miniconda introduced with the script I used to automatically activate the environment. Manual activation solved the issue. Full code of `.scikit-learn-post-link.bat` is below. You can try to run it manually to see where the issue could come from. In your case it seems something is with an access to %PREFIX% folder.

```
@echo off

@REM There is some ability to run 32-bit and 64-bit applications on Windows. If the
@REM default subdir is 32-bit, we do not want to show this message (as there is no oneDAL).
@REM So, if the conda subdir is not win-64 -> exit.
conda config --show subdir | %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\find.exe /I "win-64"
if errorlevel 1 exit /b 0

(
echo.
echo.
echo     Windows 64-bit packages of scikit-learn can be accelerated using scikit-learn-intelex.
echo     More details are available here: https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex
echo.
echo     For example:
echo.
echo         $ conda install scikit-learn-intelex
echo         $ python -m sklearnex my_application.py
echo.
) >> "%PREFIX%\.messages.txt"
```